# How can I return a pass percentage with joins?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a quality pass rate that displays a % of total instances.  So if my first statement returns 18 and my total is 29, I want to display 62.1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EVENTS 
RIGHT JOIN EVENTATTRIBUTES ON EVENTS.EVENT_NUM = EVENTATTRIBUTES.EVENT_NUM 
WHERE EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE='QUALITY REVIEW'
AND (EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_NAME='QR PASS' AND EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_AS_CHAR='1');

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM EVENTS 
RIGHT JOIN EVENTATTRIBUTES ON EVENTS.EVENT_NUM = EVENTATTRIBUTES.EVENT_NUM 
WHERE EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE='QUALITY REVIEW' 
AND (EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_NAME='QR PASS');
```

The individual select statements work fine, but I've tried a ton of different ways to combine them into a single statement and my output isn't correct.  Below is the closest I seem to get.  It seems backwards but I haven't had much luck seeing what each piece is returning, which is making it difficult to trouble shoot.  It's currently returning 5.555.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 100.0  / (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM EVENTS 
RIGHT JOIN EVENTATTRIBUTES ON EVENTS.EVENT_NUM = EVENTATTRIBUTES.EVENT_NUM 
WHERE EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE='QUALITY REVIEW'
AND (EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_NAME='QR PASS' AND EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_AS_CHAR='1'));
```

Comment: Please *tag* your specific database. your all-caps SQL is particularly hard to read and would benefit from *aliases*. Please add sample data and expected results including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your queries as table expressions of a main query that can compute the percentage. For example:

```
select
  100.0 * a.cnt / b.cnt  
from (
  -- query 1 here
  select count(*) as cnt from events...
) a
cross join (
  .. query 2 here
  select count(*) as cnt from events...
) b
```

Or, you can compress it without using subqueries by using conditional aggregation. For example:

```
SELECT
  100.0 *
  sum(case when EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_AS_CHAR='1' then 1 else 0 end)
  /
  COUNT(*) 
FROM EVENTS 
JOIN EVENTATTRIBUTES ON EVENTS.EVENT_NUM = EVENTATTRIBUTES.EVENT_NUM 
WHERE EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE='QUALITY REVIEW'
AND EVENTATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_NAME='QR PASS'
```

**Note**: I changed the `RIGHT JOIN` to just `JOIN` since it's being silently converted to an inner join by the predicate `EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE='QUALITY REVIEW'`.